# hamburger menu icon transition issue scss

Tags: html, css, sass

I am having some trouble with the transition property trying to include the all keyword.

I've included a fiddle and I feel I'm either making a simple (or stupid) mistake or something? I've seen the all keyword work fine? And it seems to working fine on the .on class when selecting them?

Why is the base classes that use the

```
// not working
transition: 0.2s transform, 0.2s all 0.4s;
// working
transition: 0.2s transform, 0.2s top 0.4s, 0.2s margin-top 0.4s;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/us2196np/2/

Comment: Never tried this but i guess setting "all" and something else doesn't work.

Comment: I thought that but I've seen it in other peoples code and it works fine. Also I have it lower down in my css to reverse the animation and no problems there either @AlexG

Comment: Well it works for me when adding the class `.on`. I suppose it should work on clicking? Your JS action doesn't add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's about priority

[look](https://jsfiddle.net/CRIP/us2196np/4/)

`transition: 0.2s all 0.4s, transform 0.2s ;`

i mean fisrt it sets transition to all styles then it rewrites transform

Comment: I thought I tried this and didn't work clearly made a typo somewhere. Thanks! @AsanAbildin